# How to return to stock Android after installing Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

Whenever I try and uncompress the tar file, I get this:

```
tar (child): nakasi-jro03d-factory-e102ba72.tg: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu. So I'm pretty sure that's my fault. So I just compress it manually using the GUI. But when I try to flash it, I get

```
sudo: ./flash-all.sh: command not found
```

Comment: What exact command are you running?  It looks as if you left out the 'z' on the file name.  Make sure you run `tar zxvf nakasi-jro03d-factory-e102ba72.tgz`

Comment: $ tar zxvf nakasi-jro03d-factory-e102ba72.tgz
tar (child): nakasi-jro03d-factory-e102ba72.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now


thats what i put in.

Comment: What directory were you in when you ran sudo ./flash-all.sh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, place your Nexus into fastboot mode.  To do this, turn the nexus off, and then turn it back on while holding the volume down button.  You should see a green android guy in the center.  Plug this into your laptop/desktop via USB.

Now, run these commands in a terminal one at a time:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/nakasi-jro03d-factory-e102ba72.tgz
tar zxvf nakasi-jro03d-factory-e102ba72.tgz
cd nakasi-jro03d/
sudo ./flash-all.sh
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks soo much that definitely did the trick i really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Chris, do you have a link to a site presenting that image file and updates? It's unclear to me whether it is stock Android for Nexus 7 or 10, and I'd also like to read about updates.

Comment: I should be spanked for not googling first: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images