# restoring my nexus 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t return to stock Android](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211987/cant-return-to-stock-android)

i have ran through the process to install ubuntu on my asus google nexus 7 tablet. i would like to restore it back to android os 4.1 or 4.2. i have used the how to guide on here and i am unable to get any of the commands to run or work in terminal. please tell me what i need to do. i have the jro03d file and the jop40c file and neither are running for me. from terminal what little i understand of it, it is having trouble with the zxvf part?

Comment: could you paste any particular error messages you're getting?