# Nexus 7 won't start when I format a partition as "MS-DOS"

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I put Ubuntu 12.10 onto my Nexus 7 just to see what it looks like. I noticed that I only had 6 GB of space of storage even though I have a 32 GB tablet. So I downloaded GParted and tried to edit the partition but noticed that there was no partition and it told me I need to create a Partitioning Table. I do not know much about harddrives so I decided to create one to see if it fixes my problem. So I created an "MS-DOS" Partitioning Table and rebooted my device. It will not start. It just stays at a black screen and does nothing. I have tried these commands:

```
"sudo fastboot reboot" -result: stuck at Waiting for Device
"sudo fastboot reset" -result: stuck at Waiting for Device
```

Note: I can **not** get a replacement and I **need** to get this fixed. I am willing to erase everything on my tablet if I need to.

Comment: Can you enter fastboot mode? Try pressing power and then volume down when starting up. If you can't, then it appears you erased everything, even the bootloader. You will have to get a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

First try to reinstall Android. Here's a good explanation how this can be done:

[How to return to stock Android after installing Ubuntu Touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211987/cant-return-to-stock-android/215036#215036)

Then try to follow carefully the instructions how to install Ubuntu touch:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

and let us know if it works, what happens, and what the outcome is. If this works well then consider not using gparted without some research about gparted on tablet computers.

Answer (score -2):

Boot your LiveCD again and reinstall Ubuntu.

What you say is you only created a partition table, but **you must also create partition**(s). If you do not know much about partitioning, best way is to install Ubuntu choosing one of the default options.

If you want to learn more about the subject,

you can read more here: [How to Partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition)
and here: [Partitioning for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/partitioning.html)

Comment: Nexus 7 is an Android Tablet. You cannot boot it with a CD.

Comment: right, no USB?? How did he install Ubuntu then??

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Comment: Ahh, right, thanks. Am bit backwards here methinks...